# apt-get update shows after upgrade to stretch still jessie

Tags: debian, apt

I upgraded from Jessie to Debian  Stretch:

```
cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
```

When I run `apt-get update`
it still checks jessie sources:
example:

```
Ign:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main Translation-de_DE
Ign:7 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main Translation-de
Ign:10 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list contains only:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: what about files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the debian version on all the files on /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  as A.B. suggests and it fixed the issue for me too.